# How to find which faces of objects are facing with others in 3D?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry

I would like to know is there any method to solve this problem:

let say i have two objects A and B in 3D (in this case cube A and cube B). How can i find which face of object A are facing a face of object B?

i have tried to post an image to make my question more clear. but i could not post it here. however i have posted this image at the other link. this is the link for my question with image.

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/191020?p_p_auth=YNRwwp6r

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning ?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "facing"? Do you have some threshold on the angle between the normals of the faces? Should this take occlusion by other objects into account?

Comment: What is a object? Polyhedron, surface mesh, parametric, ...

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. i have edited my question and put some links so that you can see the situation that i have mentioned. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project the polygon B onto the plane of support of face A. This is best done by rotating space so that A becomes parallel to the XY plane, and dropping all Z coordinates. You will know if B faces A if the two 2D polygons intersect each other (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton).

You may additionally check if all B vertices are on the same side of the plane of support by checking the signs of the Z coordinates.